# How to setImageDrawable to a View

Tags: imageview, children, insert-image

Noob to Java so I have limited knowledge.  I have 2 RelativeLayouts which will hold images of a 13 card hand.  One for all the cards and one slightly offset which show which cards can be played.  Xml is fairly straight forward

```
           <!--Player viewable cards-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="680dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/rlUserViewCards">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:src="@drawable/c001"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:tag="1"
            android:id="@+id/card1"
            android:clickable="false">
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:src="@drawable/c002"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:id="@+id/card2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card1"
            android:layout_marginTop="-65dp"
            android:clickable="false">
        </ImageView>
```

and so on for 13 Images.  I can then create a View of the relativelayout looping through the children making images INVISIBLE/VISIBLE, Clickable or not.  Does this seem like a good approach?

If so, my problem when first setting the relativelayout is that I can do above as well as set Tag with the card value, I can't figure how to get the integer for the ImageView via findViewById.

```
            userViewCards = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlUserViewCards);
    userPickCards = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlUserPlayCards);
    View v = userViewCards.getChildAt(0);
    Resources res = getResources();
    int resId = res.getIdentifier("s204", "drawable", getPackageName());  
    Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), res.getIdentifier("s204", "drawable", getPackageName()), null);
    ImageView insertImage = (ImageView) findViewById(??);  
    insertImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a tag value to the imageView and recieve it in your activity as follows

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/c001"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:tag="1"
        android:id="@+id/card1"
        android:clickable="false">


@OnClick({R.id.card1, R.id.card2, R.id.card3, R.id.card4})
public void selectedCard(View view) {

    String selectedCard = view.getTag().toString();
    Log.d(TAG, "Mode Selected : " + mode);

    switch (Integer.parseInt(mode)) {
        case Constant.Card1:
            // Do something here
            break;
        case Constant.Card2:
            // Do something here
            break;
        case Constant.Card3:
            // Do something here
            break;
        case Constant.Card4:
            // Do something here
    }
}
```

Note : I am using butterknife here hence the @OnClick()

Comment: Hmmm, I was hoping to use the Tag to hold the value of the playing card so I can check it later to manipulate the property.  Perhaps I can use it when I initialize and then later change it to card value.

Comment: DOH!  didn't realize there was a getId().

Comment: So  int imageId = v.getId(); will get me the location!